# Import facebook SDK to cordova/phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-sdk-3.0, cordova-3

I'm creating my first app using cordova 3.3.0 (aka phonegap).
Everything's all right : I can run project on to Android Device Emulator and on to my mobile.

I'd like to use the facebook connect plugin :
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

But all the documentation I read (particularly : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) explains how to set up the Facebook SDK through Eclipse. I've also found doc on how to install in Androïd Studio.

I don't want to install neither of them, I do all in command line since I like to know how things works (at least for my first projetc ...).

So the question is : how do I import facebook SDK into my cordova project ?

Thanks for your ideas !

Answer (score 7):

Alright I found the answer, was struggling with the exact same problem.
I was actually trying to get an ionic cordova project to use the facebook plugin

You have to go inside the Platform/android folder of your cordova project. At this point , you are just dealing with a regular android project

run the following command

`android update project --target 3 --path C:\Users\<yourname>\Documents\Projects\<projectName>\ionic\platforms\android --library ../../../../facebook-android-sdk-3.7/facebook`

Alright a couple of tricks

- The --library argument needs to be relative to your android project. And the library argument should refer to the facebook SDK you downloaded ( as part of the facebook plugin instructions)
- You have to have API level 8 on the android SDK
- Once the command completes, go to local.properties and check if the sdk.dir is set properly. Mine had double slashes, I had to fix that
- go to project. properties and you should see something like the following

  **android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib**

  **android.library.reference.2=../../../../facebook-android-sdk-3.7/facebook
  target=android-18'**

Hope this helps someone, I'm not too fond of using eclipse for phonegap either.

Comment: it happened to me i have to run `android update project` in the downloaded facebook sdk project too (because facebook sdk project itself doesn't know where android sdk was installed). so i cd into facebook-android-sdk/facebook and run `android project update --path . --target 4`

Answer (score 1):

Faced also the same problem today with cordova 3.3. Solution is similar to the other one given, maybe can be helpful. I am on linux environemnt

I managed to build by:

installing the plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="yourvalues" --variable APP_NAME="yourvalues"
cd /platforms/android
```

add this line to project.properties

```
android.library.reference.2=FacebookLib
```

update the project

```
android update project --subprojects --path . --target "android-19"
```

Then compiled successfully with

```
cordova build
```