# Cordova 3.4 Facebook connect, add Library

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I updated to *Cordova 3.4* and want to use the newest version of the *facebook connect* (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) plugin. I followed the steps there.

But I do not use eclipse to develop. So I need to add the Facebook library by command line.

I followed the steps [of Abdullah in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244444/import-facebook-sdk-to-cordova-phonegab-project/22912926#22912926).

My folder structure:

```
+ platforms
  + android
    ...
+ plugins
  + ...
+ facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0
  + facebook
    ...
```

I ran in `platforms/android/` this command:

```
android update project --target 3 --path . --library ../../facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0/facebook/
```

But now I'm stuck with the following error:

```
facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0/facebook/build.xml:46: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var
```

during the build with `cordova build android` do you have an idea how I could fix this?

My `platforms/android/project.properties` looks like this:

```
...
# Project target.
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=../../facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0/facebook/
```

My `platforms/android/local.properties` looks like this:

```
...
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Users/<username>/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk
```

which is correct as well.

The complete output of `cordova build android`:

```
cordova build android
[ReferenceError: a is not defined]
Running command: /Users/<username>/App_Entwicklung/20/<application>/platforms/android/cordova/build args=[]
    Buildfile:/Users/<username>/App_Entwicklung/20/<application>/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /Users/<username>/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: <application>20
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for <application>20...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.3
[gettarget] API level:        18
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for <application>20...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

BUILD FAILED
/Users/<username>/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/<username>/App_Entwicklung/20/<application>/facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0/facebook/build.xml:46: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var

Total time: 0 seconds
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/<username>/App_Entwicklung/20/<application>/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/<username>/App_Entwicklung/20/<application>/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Comment: why don't you follow the official phonegap site guide??? https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md

Comment: Actually I added the *Setup without Eclipse (just CLI) * Section in this document on my own. So I provided the solution for it. I didn't want to use Eclipse for that, because it is no real solution for my building environment. (And actually, the question is already 7 months old ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a guide how to setup the Facebook Plugin without eclipse. It is already part of the installation guidelines on the repository. Check it out at: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your actual project but in the android Facebook SDK and occurs because the FacebookSDK android project isn't able to locate the Android SDK.

To fix it:

1. Navigate to your FacebookSDK folder (for me this is facebook-android-sdk-3.8.0/facebook) and look for the project.properties file.
2. Edit this file and specify the path to the sdk (like you did for your core project).
   sdk.dir=/Users//Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk
3. Save and rebuild.

Comment: I tried what you said, but still giving the same error. Modified on `plugins/..` and the `platform/android/..`

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your facebook-sdk-3.8.0/facebook folder and run the following command

```
 android update project -p .
```

(keep the dot at the end)

Comment: Got this error after doing this:

Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command.
It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
please use the --subprojects parameter.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a --target

Comment: Where you inside your facebook-sdk-3.x.0/facebook folder? What did you specify in the --target?

Comment: Lucas, for that I did --target 3.
However, I had to revert to 0.4.0 of FacebookConnect to get everything working.

http://t.co/hJYZonK385

Comment: Very nice guide. But this plugin is awful. I use this one and I'm very happy about it: https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-facebook. The Christophe Coenraets's one you suggest isn't good enough cause it's just a popup, which means it doesn't get the session from the native FB app, so the user always has to type in login and pass even if he has the fb app installed and logged.

Comment: I didn't know about the ccsoft one. I like this plugin for now at least. Just so stupid how hard it is to implement. I'll make sure to keep that one in mind, thanks!

Christophe Coenraets' does have it's flaws, but if you are in a pinch and need something it can be the filler for the time being until you get a better SSO plugin.